# Why thin plastic films stick to glass?

Tags: forces

What is the mechanism for a thin plastic film to stick tightly to a clean glass surface? I can understand that effect if there's a sort of a liquid between these (and it's probably the surface tension to blame), but the phenomenon also occurs when the surfaces are totally dry - as a protective film on a new mobile phone's screen.

Comment: seems to be an electrostatic effect , at least for cling film  http://www.sciencefocus.com/qa/why-does-clingfilm-cling

Comment: Here is a manufacturer's web site. http://www.surfaceguard.com/productsolutions/surfaceguard.html. They say they use a presure sensitive clean peel adhesive.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove all the air between glass and the film, the air pressure in the exposed side let it to stick with the glass surface. With the thin and smooth film, it is easier to remove all the air between itself and another smooth surface such as glass.